# Drupal 8 receiving form values on mail

Tags: php, forms, drupal, drupal-8

With my code I receive emails with the body and subject from `hook_mail` instead of the submitted form values.

In `mymodule.module` I implement `hook_mail` which see below :

```
**
 * Implements hook_mail().
 */
function contactfrancais_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
$options = array(
    'langcode' => 'fr'
);

switch ($key) {
  case 'nouveau contact':
    $from = \Drupal::config('system.site')->get('mail');
    $message['subject'] ='Nouvelle message';
    $message['body'][] = (t('test body'));

      break;
}
```

Then in my `form.php` the following submit handler :

```
/**
  * {@inheritdoc}
  */
 public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state){

 $langcode = 'fr';
 $to = 'mymail@gmail.com';

 $mailManager = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.mail');
 $module = 'contactfrancais';
 $key = 'nouveau contact';
 $params = array(
 'body' => 'test',
 'subject' => 'Website Information Request',
  );
 $send = true;
 $message['subject'] = t('nouveau contact');
 $message['body'][] = t('test');

 $result = $mailManager->mailç$module,$key,$to,$langcode,$params,
 NULL,$send);
 }
```

When I reference to the `$params` values or reference to the `$form_state` values in my `hook_mail` I get an undefined value error. How can I reference to the form values? I tried with `getvalue()`, `getValues()`, `$form_values`, ... all giving errors.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest minor changes in your code, as a simple solution.

You can use placeholders in your mail body, and replace with actual values - in your submit handler.

Change your code like this.

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state){
    $langcode = 'fr';
    $to = 'mymail@gmail.com';

    $mailManager = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.mail');
    $module = 'contactfrancais';
    $key = 'nouveau contact';
    $body_text = 'New contact: <br />{submitted_value1}<br />{submitted_value2}<br />{submitted_value3}<br />';

    $value1 = $form_values['submitted_value1'];
    $value2 = $form_values['submitted_value2'];
    $value3 = $form_values['submitted_value3'];
    $body_text = str_replace('{submitted_value1}', $value1, $body_text);
    $body_text = str_replace('{submitted_value2}', $value2, $body_text);
    $body_text = str_replace('{submitted_value3}', $value3, $body_text);
    $params = array(
        'body' => $body_text,
        'subject' => t('nouveau contact')
    );
    $send = true;

    $result = $mailManager->mail($module,$key,$to,$langcode,$params,NULL,$send);
}

**
 * Implements hook_mail().
 */
function contactfrancais_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
    $options = array(
        'langcode' => 'fr'
    );

    switch ($key) {
      case 'nouveau contact':
        $from = \Drupal::config('system.site')->get('mail');
        $message['subject'] = $params['subject'];
        $message['body'][] = $params['body'];
        break;
    }
}
```